# Hidden div takes up height in Bootstrap modal body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a `div` inside of a Bootstrap modal dialog, using the [AngularJS directives for Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

The visibility of the `div` is hidden by default. This will change later on in response to a user action (e.g., clicking a button or form field). The problem I'm having is, even though the `div` is hidden, its contents are still occupying space in the modal body.

In other words, the height of the modal body includes the contents of the hidden `div`, even though it's hidden. I don't want this to happen.

Here's a contrived example of the modal template, including the `div` that I have set to hidden in the CSS:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.tmpl.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Modal</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <div>I'm a modal.</div>
    <div class="hidden-div">
      Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test
      <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/> Test <br/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    Modal footer here
  </div>
</script>
```

It's probably easier to demonstrate what I mean with a fiddle. If you check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hz6k2g3/19/), and click "Open Me", you should see what I mean.

The `div` with all of the "test" text is hidden, but the height of the modal body is still based off of it. How can I fix this?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hidden-div` makes use of `visibility: hidden`. Although it hides the contents, but doesn't makes up for the space.

Read more about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone).

To solve it, one should make use of `display` as below:

```
.hidden-div {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using visibility use the `display` property. 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

```
.hidden-div {
  display: none;
}
```